# How to scrape in laravel 5.2 using Goutte?

Tags: php, web-scraping, laravel-5, goutte

I am new to Laravel 5.2, I want to scrape a web page. I came to know that it can be done by using [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte). And in don't know how to use it.

I have installed Laravel and Goutte, But how to use it? How to set Controller, route and all things which are required?

Comment: I have just installed the library file

Comment: Are you wanting to use Goutte inside the web app? This is possible, though I usually do this inside a console program outside of the web server (since scraping is a slow activity and you don't want to hold up your web server). A good first approach is to create a quick console program to do the scraping you wish to do, and get it working there (i.e. completely without Laravel). You can do a basic scrape in Goutte in about 10 lines of code.

Comment: Did you try the Goutte examples in the repo `README`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found my answer.
I just add the url to route and created the controller

```
Route::resource('scrape','WebScraperController@index');
```

Inside the WebScraperController

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Goutte\Client;
  use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
  use App\Http\Requests;
  class WebScraperController extends Controller
  {
  public function index()
  {
  //  Create a new Goutte client instance
    $client = new Client();

 //  Hackery to allow HTTPS
    $guzzleclient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'timeout' => 60,
        'verify' => false,
    ]);

    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html('https://www.facebook.com');

    // Find all images
    foreach ($html->find('img') as $element) {
        echo $element->src . '<br>';
    }

    // Find all links
    foreach ($html->find('a') as $element) {
        echo $element->href . '<br>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Call to undefined function Vanguard\Http\Controllers\web\file_get_html()